# Can't determine the cause of syntax error for this rails error message to my products form.html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a tutorial from my coding college as im creating a rails web store application.

for my product controller i am using simple forms gem to create the "create product" "edit product" forms and as per the tutorial the below syntax should be correct:

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error :base %>
      <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors [:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors [:base].present? %>

      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :description %>
        <%= f.input :price %>
        <%= f.input :category, :collection ["footwear", "accessories", "menswear", "womenswear"] %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I am receiving an error for line 3 however when trying to input the above in my _form.html.erb file:

SyntaxError: /Users/Sneha1/Desktop/sbhamra/streetwear_app/app/views/products/_form.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected [, expecting ')' ...tion message: f.object.errors [:base].to_sentence if f.objec... ... ^

If someone can please look at this and help me figure out what I've done wrong that would be great!

Comment: I can't see an error on line 3, but I can see an error on line 9... it should be `collection: ['footwear', ...etc]` (colon follows 'collection')

Comment: I see a space between `f.object.errors [:base]` It should be `f.object.errors[:base]` no space. That's the error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ruby has trouble parsing a hash with a conditional value. It needs help from some parentheses.

```rb
foo = "bar"

hsh = {qux: foo if foo.present?} #=> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
```

but with some parsing guidance from some parentheses:

```rb
foo = "bar"

hsh = {qux: (foo if foo.present?)} #=> {:qux => "bar"}
```

so try writing your line 3 like this:

```rb
<%= f.error_notification message: (f.object.errors [:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors [:base].present?) %>
```

or, more concisely::

```rb
<%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base]&.to_sentence %>
```